# How to get aws lambda function name at CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I can get the details with

```
$ aws lambda get-function --function-name random_number
{
    "Configuration": {
        "FunctionName": "random_number",
        "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:193693970645:function:random_number",
        "Runtime": "ruby2.5",
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::193693970645:role/service-role/random_number-role-8cy8a1a7",
        ...
```

But how can  get just a couple of fields like function name ?

I tried:

```
$ aws lambda get-function --function-name random_number --query "Configuration[*].[FunctionName]"
```

but I get `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overall approach is correct, you just need to adjust the query:

```
$ aws lambda get-function --function-name random_number \
      --query "Configuration.FunctionName" --output text
```

I also added a parameter to convert the result to text, which makes processing a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `awk` (standard Linux gnu awk) script that does the trick: Extract the values of quoted field #3, only for line having /FunctionName/.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="\"[^\"]+"}/FunctionName/{print substr($3,2)}'
```

Piped with your initial command:

```
$ aws lambda get-function --function-name random_number | awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="\"[^\"]+"}/FunctionName/{print substr($3,2)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is by using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).
therefore, the output must be JSON.

From the docs :

> jq is like sed for JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter and
>   map and transform structured data with the same ease that sed, awk,
>   grep and friends let you play with text.

Usage example :

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name test --output json | jq -r '.Configuration.FunctionName'
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `get-function-configuration` as in the following:

```
aws lambda get-function-configuration --function-name MyFunction --query "[FunctionName]"
```